# Nature of improper integral following values of $\alpha$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

It is asked to study the nature of the improper integral

$$ \displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty} \dfrac{\ln(\arctan(x))}{x^\alpha} dx $$

At $+\infty$, it seems it converges for $\alpha > 1$ since the numerator is bounded and positive for sufficiently large $x$.

What about the problem at $0$.

Thanks for any hints / replies.

Comment: The integrand behaves like $\ln(x)/x^\alpha$ at zero.

Comment: Have you used the equivalents ? I think the implication $u \sim v \implies ln(u) \sim ln(v)$ is not always true

Comment: If $u(x) = v(x) + o(v(x))$ and $v$ is positive, then $\ln u = \ln v + \ln(1 + o(v)/v)$.